# Is it possible to make website content available on another website?

Tags: api

Please I need help making website content available on another website through an API or something. Is this possible to achieve?

I'd appreciate your response.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem that this solves? Usually there's a better way of doing it, but there isn't much context or information to go on here, the question is too generic

Comment: Yes to expand on @TomJNowell's question you need to add some specifics such as what content is it you want displayed on another site, and how? WP gives you access to its content through it's API, but just getting raw content may not be what you need, for example because of missing headers, styles, etc.

Comment: The crude one word answer is ***yes***, but how you would do that is a huge subject that depends on what this content is and what you mean. Importing an RSS feed is a cmpletely different subject to scraping a site, or syndicating data, or sharing posts across sites, importing tweets, etc etc, and is this happening once? Is it a site migration? Does it happen in realtime? Every 30 minutes? When an event happens? Is it an archive of the other site? ***To be able to answer this, we need to know more. Use the edit link to explain and add context***

Answer (score -1):

You can use wp all in one migration plugin to fully move your website to another. or use wordpress admin dashboard -> Tools -> export and then Tools -> Import the xml file in other website.
if you are using page builder then they have their own export/import.